# How to change bootstrap data color attribute in a html file

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, colors

I am working on a template and wish to change the background color of the div below: 
 `<div class="sidebar" data-active-color="blue" data-background-color="wihte">` 
 I noticed that i can only toggle between black and white for the `data-background-color` attribute. 
Every other color choice aside white and black reverts back to the default white color.
How can i change this color to the color of my choice (green in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar" style="background: green;">TEXT </div>

<br/>

<div class="sidebar bg-success" >TEXT </div>
```

I believe that it cant be done that way. You can however add `bg-success` class to it or `style="background: green;"`
Also check this: http://bootstrap-colorselector.flaute.com/

Comment: i have tried to add style to it and it still reverts to the default white

Comment: it works on the snippet? try it like this `style="background: green!important;"` or try `bg-success` class

Answer (score 0):

What type of event? When should the color change?

```
$('.sidebar').on('click', function(){
    $(this).attr('data-background-color', 'green');
})
```

Comment: the color should change when the page loads. it should be constant